# Asymptotic integral computation takes too long

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, series-expansion

I am trying to understand how grows the function $k\mapsto\int_{0}^{\infty} \left({1 - \left(1 - \exp(-t/k)\right)^k}\right)dt$ for $k\to\infty$, and I expect a result asymptotically equal to $k\log(k)$. However, the following command, takes too much time:

```
Series[Integrate[1 - (1 - Exp[-t/k])^k, {t,0,\[Infinity]}],{k,\[Infinity],3}]
```

---

**Question:** Should I modify something in the command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that this integral is equal to `k*HarmonicNumber[k]` and therefore the expansion is given by

```
Series[k*HarmonicNumber[k],{k,Infinity,3}]
(* (EulerGamma+Log[k]) k+1/2-1/(12 k)+1/(120 k^3)+O[1/k]^4 *)
```

To derive this, I did a little bit of manual work: I made the substitution $1-e^{-t/k} = s$ which transforms OP's integral to the following integral, which Mathematica evaluates:

```
k*Integrate[(1-s^k)/(1-s),{s,0,1},GenerateConditions->False]
(* k HarmonicNumber[k] *)
```

Here is code to check the claim directly in some examples:

```
Table[FullSimplify[
   Integrate[1-(1-Exp[-t/k])^k,{t,0,Infinity}]==k*HarmonicNumber[k]],
 {k,{1/2,1,4,100/3}}]
(* {True,True,True,True} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! BTW, I am surprised that it needs manual work, which cannot be done my the software. My goal is actually to evaluate how asymptotically grows `Integrate[(1-Product[1-Exp[-2jt/(k*(k+1))], {j, 1, k}]), {t,0,\[Infinity]}]` for $k\to\infty$, but at this point, I still do not know how to proceed. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I am not sure if it needs manual work. Since Version 13.3 there is also [IntegrateChangeVariables](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegrateChangeVariables.html) but I have not tried it. Concerning your more difficult integral, I do not have an immediate answer. Maybe you want to submit it as a new question?

Answer (score 7):

A different approach for the same result as user293787 obtained

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[k_] := Integrate[1 - (1 - Exp[-t/k])^k, {t, 0, ∞}]
```

Evaluate `f` for several positive integers

```
seq = f /@ Range[10]

(* {1, 3, 11/2, 25/3, 137/12, 147/10, 363/20, 761/35, 
  7129/280, 7381/252} *)
```

Use [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to generalize from the sequence

```
f2[k_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, k] // FullSimplify

(* k HarmonicNumber[k] *)
```

Compare with numeric evaluation of the integral

```
f3[k_?NumericQ] :=
 NIntegrate[1 - (1 - Exp[-t/k])^k, {t, 0, ∞}]

Plot[{k*Log[k], f2[k], f3[k]}, {k, 0, 1000},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, {Red, Dashed}},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.3, .7}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! My goal is actually to evaluate how asymptotically grows `Integrate[(1-Product[1-Exp[-2jt/(k*(k+1))], {j, 1, k}]), {t,0,\[Infinity]}]` for $k\to\infty$, but it is not clear to me whether I can operate as you did above. Do you have any idea?

Comment: This is a separate question. Post a new question so that more people will see it (few will read questions in comments and some many only look at questions with no answers).